# Upgraded from SQLite3 to PG - db is 100 times slower

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, sqlite, database-performance

Just streamlined my dev environment and switched from SQLite3 to PG so it's the same on my production environment.
The same working code that I had before is now taking much, MUCH more time than it did before.
Haven't changed anything except installing pg.

Before PG:

```
Processing by CollectionsController#show as HTML
  Parameters: {"keyword"=>"cat and dog towel", "id"=>"37"}
  Collection Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "collections".* FROM "collections" WHERE "collections"."id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["id", 37], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  Seller Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "sellers".* FROM "sellers" WHERE "sellers"."id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["id", 13], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  User Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT ?  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
   (0.1ms)  commit transaction
  Search Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "searches".* FROM "searches" WHERE "searches"."term" = ? LIMIT ?  [["term", "cat and dog towel"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  Listing Load (1.4ms)  SELECT  DISTINCT "listings".* FROM "listings" INNER JOIN "listings_searches" ON "listings"."id" = "listings_searches"."listing_id" WHERE "listings_searches"."search_id" = ? ORDER BY "listings"."id" ASC LIMIT ?  [["search_id", 775], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  Search Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "searches".* FROM "searches" WHERE "searches"."term" = ? ORDER BY "searches"."id" ASC LIMIT ?  [["term", "Beach Towel"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
  Search Exists (0.2ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "searches" WHERE "searches"."term" = ? LIMIT ?  [["term", "Beach Towel"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  SQL (0.5ms)  INSERT INTO "searches" ("term", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?)  [["term", "Beach Towel"], ["created_at", "2018-06-18 12:47:58.519223"], ["updated_at", "2018-06-18 12:47:58.519223"]]
   (7.0ms)  commit transaction
  Item Exists (0.3ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "items" WHERE "items"."search_id" = ? AND "items"."collection_id" = 37 LIMIT ?  [["search_id", 776], ["LIMIT", 1]]
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
  Collection Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "collections".* FROM "collections" WHERE "collections"."id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["id", 37], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  Item Exists (0.2ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "items" WHERE "items"."collection_id" = ? AND "items"."search_id" = 776 LIMIT ?  [["collection_id", 37], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  SQL (2.3ms)  INSERT INTO "items" ("collection_id", "search_id", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)  [["collection_id", 37], ["search_id", 776], ["created_at", "2018-06-18 12:47:58.540021"], ["updated_at", "2018-06-18 12:47:58.540021"]]
   (6.2ms)  commit transaction
Started GET "/sellers/16" for 127.0.0.1 at 2018-06-18 15:48:00 +0300
Processing by SellersController#show as HTML
  Parameters: {"id"=>"16"}
  Search Load (5.5ms)  SELECT  "searches".* FROM "searches" WHERE "searches"."term" = ? ORDER BY "searches"."id" ASC LIMIT ?  [["term", "Bath Towel"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
  Search Exists (0.2ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "searches" WHERE "searches"."term" = ? LIMIT ?  [["term", "Bath Towel"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  SQL (1.4ms)  INSERT INTO "searches" ("term", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?)  [["term", "Bath Towel"], ["created_at", "2018-06-18 12:48:01.250699"], ["updated_at", "2018-06-18 12:48:01.250699"]]
  Seller Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "sellers".* FROM "sellers" WHERE "sellers"."id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["id", 16], ["LIMIT", 1]]
   (9.6ms)  commit transaction
  User Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT ?  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  Item Exists (0.3ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "items" WHERE "items"."search_id" = ? AND "items"."collection_id" = 37 LIMIT ?  [["search_id", 777], ["LIMIT", 1]]
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
  Collection Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "collections".* FROM "collections" WHERE "collections"."id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["id", 37], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  Item Exists (0.2ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "items" WHERE "items"."collection_id" = ? AND "items"."search_id" = 777 LIMIT ?  [["collection_id", 37], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  SQL (1.0ms)  INSERT INTO "items" ("collection_id", "search_id", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)  [["collection_id", 37], ["search_id", 777], ["created_at", "2018-06-18 12:48:01.285942"], ["updated_at", "2018-06-18 12:48:01.285942"]]
  Shop Load (8.8ms)  SELECT  "shops".* FROM "shops" WHERE "shops"."seller_id" = ? ORDER BY "shops"."id" DESC LIMIT ?  [["seller_id", 16], ["LIMIT", 1]]
   (40.2ms)  commit transaction
  Rendering sellers/show.html.erb within layouts/application
   (0.4ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "listings" WHERE "listings"."shop_id" = 12
  Listing Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  "listings".* FROM "listings" WHERE "listings"."shop_id" = 12 LIMIT ? OFFSET ?  [["LIMIT", 24], ["OFFSET", 0]]
  Rendered sellers/show.html.erb within layouts/application (4.8ms)
  Rendered layouts/_shim.html.erb (0.4ms)
  Rendered layouts/_rails_default.html.erb (93.9ms)
  Rendered layouts/_meta.html.erb (0.3ms)
  Seller Exists (0.3ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "sellers" WHERE "sellers"."user_id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["user_id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  Seller Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "sellers".* FROM "sellers" WHERE "sellers"."user_id" = ? ORDER BY "sellers"."id" DESC LIMIT ?  [["user_id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  Rendered layouts/_header.html.erb (5.5ms)
  Seller Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "sellers".* FROM "sellers" WHERE "sellers"."user_id" = ?  [["user_id", 1]]
  Shop Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "shops".* FROM "shops" WHERE "shops"."seller_id" = ? ORDER BY "shops"."id" DESC LIMIT ?  [["seller_id", 13], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  CACHE Shop Load (0.0ms)  SELECT  "shops".* FROM "shops" WHERE "shops"."seller_id" = ? ORDER BY "shops"."id" DESC LIMIT ?  [["seller_id", 16], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  Rendered layouts/_sidebar.html.erb (7.3ms)
  Rendered layouts/_end_sidebar.html.erb (0.4ms)
  Rendered layouts/_footer.html.erb (0.4ms)
Completed 200 OK in 212ms (Views: 120.5ms | ActiveRecord: 12.3ms)
```

After PG:

```
Started POST "/collections/1/item/choose.25" for 127.0.0.1 at 2018-06-18 16:56:12 +0300
Processing by ItemsController#choose as 
  Parameters: {"authenticity_token"=>"11+Rpf2qXEKhQ5vBJLWie2EBg1b2Dtrw8iIgoLwXyvake7+myDrVErcqTwNcPYAZ5xs+zFKXaJjwM7fTakXaoA==", "collection_id"=>"1"}
  Collection Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  "collections".* FROM "collections" WHERE "collections"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  Seller Load (0.6ms)  SELECT  "sellers".* FROM "sellers" WHERE "sellers"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  Item Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "items".* FROM "items" WHERE "items"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 25], ["LIMIT", 1]]
   (0.1ms)  BEGIN
  Collection Load (0.5ms)  SELECT  "collections".* FROM "collections" WHERE "collections"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  Search Load (0.9ms)  SELECT  "searches".* FROM "searches" WHERE "searches"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 31], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  Item Exists (0.7ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "items" WHERE "items"."collection_id" = $1 AND ("items"."id" != $2) AND "items"."search_id" = 31 LIMIT $3  [["collection_id", 1], ["id", 25], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  SQL (0.8ms)  UPDATE "items" SET "chosen" = $1, "updated_at" = $2 WHERE "items"."id" = $3  [["chosen", "t"], ["updated_at", "2018-06-18 13:56:12.465841"], ["id", 25]]
   (2.7ms)  COMMIT
   (0.4ms)  BEGIN
  SQL (0.6ms)  UPDATE "collections" SET "keyword" = $1, "updated_at" = $2 WHERE "collections"."id" = $3  [["keyword", "Bookish Candles"], ["updated_at", "2018-06-18 13:56:12.473173"], ["id", 1]]
   (1.5ms)  COMMIT
  Search Load (0.6ms)  SELECT  "searches".* FROM "searches" WHERE "searches"."term" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["term", "Bookish Candles"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  Listing Load (4.1ms)  SELECT  DISTINCT "listings".* FROM "listings" INNER JOIN "listings_searches" ON "listings"."id" = "listings_searches"."listing_id" WHERE "listings_searches"."search_id" = $1 ORDER BY "listings"."id" ASC LIMIT $2  [["search_id", 31], ["LIMIT", 3]]
  Search Load (0.7ms)  SELECT  "searches".* FROM "searches" WHERE "searches"."term" = $1 ORDER BY "searches"."id" ASC LIMIT $2  [["term", "soy candles"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
   (0.2ms)  BEGIN
  Search Exists (0.8ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "searches" WHERE "searches"."term" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["term", "soy candles"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  SQL (0.6ms)  INSERT INTO "searches" ("term", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3) RETURNING "id"  [["term", "soy candles"], ["created_at", "2018-06-18 13:56:12.491262"], ["updated_at", "2018-06-18 13:56:12.491262"]]
   (2.3ms)  COMMIT
  Item Exists (0.6ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "items" WHERE "items"."search_id" = $1 AND "items"."collection_id" = 1 LIMIT $2  [["search_id", 46], ["LIMIT", 1]]
   (0.2ms)  BEGIN
  Collection Load (1.3ms)  SELECT  "collections".* FROM "collections" WHERE "collections"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  Item Exists (0.7ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "items" WHERE "items"."collection_id" = $1 AND "items"."search_id" = 46 LIMIT $2  [["collection_id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  SQL (1.0ms)  INSERT INTO "items" ("collection_id", "search_id", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4) RETURNING "id"  [["collection_id", 1], ["search_id", 46], ["created_at", "2018-06-18 13:56:12.504381"], ["updated_at", "2018-06-18 13:56:12.504381"]]
   (1.1ms)  COMMIT
  Search Load (0.8ms)  SELECT  "searches".* FROM "searches" WHERE "searches"."term" = $1 ORDER BY "searches"."id" ASC LIMIT $2  [["term", "book candle"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
   (0.2ms)  BEGIN
  Search Exists (0.5ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "searches" WHERE "searches"."term" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["term", "book candle"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  SQL (0.5ms)  INSERT INTO "searches" ("term", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3) RETURNING "id"  [["term", "book candle"], ["created_at", "2018-06-18 13:56:14.812727"], ["updated_at", "2018-06-18 13:56:14.812727"]]
   (2.8ms)  COMMIT
  Item Exists (0.7ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "items" WHERE "items"."search_id" = $1 AND "items"."collection_id" = 1 LIMIT $2  [["search_id", 47], ["LIMIT", 1]]
   (0.1ms)  BEGIN
  Collection Load (1.0ms)  SELECT  "collections".* FROM "collections" WHERE "collections"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  Item Exists (0.6ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "items" WHERE "items"."collection_id" = $1 AND "items"."search_id" = 47 LIMIT $2  [["collection_id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  SQL (0.5ms)  INSERT INTO "items" ("collection_id", "search_id", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4) RETURNING "id"  [["collection_id", 1], ["search_id", 47], ["created_at", "2018-06-18 13:56:14.825865"], ["updated_at", "2018-06-18 13:56:14.825865"]]
   (1.4ms)  COMMIT
  Search Load (1.0ms)  SELECT  "searches".* FROM "searches" WHERE "searches"."term" = $1 ORDER BY "searches"."id" ASC LIMIT $2  [["term", "literary gifts"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
   (0.4ms)  BEGIN
  Search Exists (0.7ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "searches" WHERE "searches"."term" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["term", "literary gifts"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  SQL (0.7ms)  INSERT INTO "searches" ("term", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3) RETURNING "id"  [["term", "literary gifts"], ["created_at", "2018-06-18 13:56:17.776368"], ["updated_at", "2018-06-18 13:56:17.776368"]]
   (2.4ms)  COMMIT
  Item Exists (0.8ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "items" WHERE "items"."search_id" = $1 AND "items"."collection_id" = 1 LIMIT $2  [["search_id", 48], ["LIMIT", 1]]
   (0.2ms)  BEGIN
  Collection Load (1.6ms)  SELECT  "collections".* FROM "collections" WHERE "collections"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  Item Exists (0.8ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "items" WHERE "items"."collection_id" = $1 AND "items"."search_id" = 48 LIMIT $2  [["collection_id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  SQL (1.1ms)  INSERT INTO "items" ("collection_id", "search_id", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4) RETURNING "id"  [["collection_id", 1], ["search_id", 48], ["created_at", "2018-06-18 13:56:17.790424"], ["updated_at", "2018-06-18 13:56:17.790424"]]
   (1.2ms)  COMMIT
  Search Load (0.7ms)  SELECT  "searches".* FROM "searches" WHERE "searches"."term" = $1 ORDER BY "searches"."id" ASC LIMIT $2  [["term", "book candles"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
   (0.2ms)  BEGIN
  Search Exists (0.7ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "searches" WHERE "searches"."term" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["term", "book candles"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  SQL (0.6ms)  INSERT INTO "searches" ("term", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3) RETURNING "id"  [["term", "book candles"], ["created_at", "2018-06-18 13:56:20.872076"], ["updated_at", "2018-06-18 13:56:20.872076"]]
   (1.4ms)  COMMIT
  Item Exists (0.6ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "items" WHERE "items"."search_id" = $1 AND "items"."collection_id" = 1 LIMIT $2  [["search_id", 49], ["LIMIT", 1]]
   (0.1ms)  BEGIN
  Collection Load (0.6ms)  SELECT  "collections".* FROM "collections" WHERE "collections"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  Item Exists (0.7ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "items" WHERE "items"."collection_id" = $1 AND "items"."search_id" = 49 LIMIT $2  [["collection_id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  SQL (0.8ms)  INSERT INTO "items" ("collection_id", "search_id", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4) RETURNING "id"  [["collection_id", 1], ["search_id", 49], ["created_at", "2018-06-18 13:56:20.883450"], ["updated_at", "2018-06-18 13:56:20.883450"]]
   (2.3ms)  COMMIT
  Search Load (0.9ms)  SELECT  "searches".* FROM "searches" WHERE "searches"."term" = $1 ORDER BY "searches"."id" ASC LIMIT $2  [["term", "literary candles"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
   (0.2ms)  BEGIN
  Search Exists (0.5ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "searches" WHERE "searches"."term" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["term", "literary candles"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  SQL (0.8ms)  INSERT INTO "searches" ("term", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3) RETURNING "id"  [["term", "literary candles"], ["created_at", "2018-06-18 13:56:22.523896"], ["updated_at", "2018-06-18 13:56:22.523896"]]
   (1.4ms)  COMMIT
  Item Exists (0.7ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "items" WHERE "items"."search_id" = $1 AND "items"."collection_id" = 1 LIMIT $2  [["search_id", 50], ["LIMIT", 1]]
   (0.2ms)  BEGIN
  Collection Load (0.7ms)  SELECT  "collections".* FROM "collections" WHERE "collections"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  Item Exists (0.9ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "items" WHERE "items"."collection_id" = $1 AND "items"."search_id" = 50 LIMIT $2  [["collection_id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  SQL (0.9ms)  INSERT INTO "items" ("collection_id", "search_id", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4) RETURNING "id"  [["collection_id", 1], ["search_id", 50], ["created_at", "2018-06-18 13:56:22.536553"], ["updated_at", "2018-06-18 13:56:22.536553"]]
   (2.2ms)  COMMIT
  Search Load (0.9ms)  SELECT  "searches".* FROM "searches" WHERE "searches"."term" = $1 ORDER BY "searches"."id" ASC LIMIT $2  [["term", "soy candle"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  Item Exists (0.7ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "items" WHERE "items"."search_id" = $1 AND "items"."collection_id" = 1 LIMIT $2  [["search_id", 18], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  Search Load (0.6ms)  SELECT  "searches".* FROM "searches" WHERE "searches"."term" = $1 ORDER BY "searches"."id" ASC LIMIT $2  [["term", "8oz candles"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
   (0.3ms)  BEGIN
  Search Exists (0.6ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "searches" WHERE "searches"."term" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["term", "8oz candles"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  SQL (0.5ms)  INSERT INTO "searches" ("term", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3) RETURNING "id"  [["term", "8oz candles"], ["created_at", "2018-06-18 13:56:25.455733"], ["updated_at", "2018-06-18 13:56:25.455733"]]
   (2.4ms)  COMMIT
  Item Exists (0.8ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "items" WHERE "items"."search_id" = $1 AND "items"."collection_id" = 1 LIMIT $2  [["search_id", 51], ["LIMIT", 1]]
   (0.2ms)  BEGIN
  Collection Load (0.7ms)  SELECT  "collections".* FROM "collections" WHERE "collections"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  Item Exists (0.6ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "items" WHERE "items"."collection_id" = $1 AND "items"."search_id" = 51 LIMIT $2  [["collection_id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  SQL (1.0ms)  INSERT INTO "items" ("collection_id", "search_id", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4) RETURNING "id"  [["collection_id", 1], ["search_id", 51], ["created_at", "2018-06-18 13:56:25.468089"], ["updated_at", "2018-06-18 13:56:25.468089"]]
   (1.2ms)  COMMIT
  Search Load (0.7ms)  SELECT  "searches".* FROM "searches" WHERE "searches"."term" = $1 ORDER BY "searches"."id" ASC LIMIT $2  [["term", "handmade soy candles"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
   (0.2ms)  BEGIN
  Search Exists (0.5ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "searches" WHERE "searches"."term" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["term", "handmade soy candles"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  SQL (0.5ms)  INSERT INTO "searches" ("term", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3) RETURNING "id"  [["term", "handmade soy candles"], ["created_at", "2018-06-18 13:56:27.445609"], ["updated_at", "2018-06-18 13:56:27.445609"]]
   (1.3ms)  COMMIT
  Item Exists (1.1ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "items" WHERE "items"."search_id" = $1 AND "items"."collection_id" = 1 LIMIT $2  [["search_id", 52], ["LIMIT", 1]]
   (0.2ms)  BEGIN
  Collection Load (0.5ms)  SELECT  "collections".* FROM "collections" WHERE "collections"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  Item Exists (0.6ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "items" WHERE "items"."collection_id" = $1 AND "items"."search_id" = 52 LIMIT $2  [["collection_id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  SQL (0.6ms)  INSERT INTO "items" ("collection_id", "search_id", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4) RETURNING "id"  [["collection_id", 1], ["search_id", 52], ["created_at", "2018-06-18 13:56:27.457050"], ["updated_at", "2018-06-18 13:56:27.457050"]]
   (2.5ms)  COMMIT
  Search Load (0.7ms)  SELECT  "searches".* FROM "searches" WHERE "searches"."term" = $1 ORDER BY "searches"."id" ASC LIMIT $2  [["term", "bookish candle"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  Item Exists (0.6ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "items" WHERE "items"."search_id" = $1 AND "items"."collection_id" = 1 LIMIT $2  [["search_id", 13], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  Search Load (0.5ms)  SELECT  "searches".* FROM "searches" WHERE "searches"."term" = $1 ORDER BY "searches"."id" ASC LIMIT $2  [["term", "bookish candles"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
   (0.2ms)  BEGIN
  Search Exists (0.5ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "searches" WHERE "searches"."term" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["term", "bookish candles"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  SQL (1.0ms)  INSERT INTO "searches" ("term", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3) RETURNING "id"  [["term", "bookish candles"], ["created_at", "2018-06-18 13:56:29.102682"], ["updated_at", "2018-06-18 13:56:29.102682"]]
   (1.6ms)  COMMIT
  Item Exists (0.8ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "items" WHERE "items"."search_id" = $1 AND "items"."collection_id" = 1 LIMIT $2  [["search_id", 53], ["LIMIT", 1]]
   (0.3ms)  BEGIN
  Collection Load (0.5ms)  SELECT  "collections".* FROM "collections" WHERE "collections"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  Item Exists (0.5ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "items" WHERE "items"."collection_id" = $1 AND "items"."search_id" = 53 LIMIT $2  [["collection_id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  SQL (0.6ms)  INSERT INTO "items" ("collection_id", "search_id", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4) RETURNING "id"  [["collection_id", 1], ["search_id", 53], ["created_at", "2018-06-18 13:56:29.114736"], ["updated_at", "2018-06-18 13:56:29.114736"]]
   (2.1ms)  COMMIT
  Search Load (1.0ms)  SELECT  "searches".* FROM "searches" WHERE "searches"."term" = $1 ORDER BY "searches"."id" ASC LIMIT $2  [["term", "personalized gifts"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
   (0.2ms)  BEGIN
  Search Exists (0.8ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "searches" WHERE "searches"."term" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["term", "personalized gifts"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  SQL (0.8ms)  INSERT INTO "searches" ("term", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3) RETURNING "id"  [["term", "personalized gifts"], ["created_at", "2018-06-18 13:56:30.446268"], ["updated_at", "2018-06-18 13:56:30.446268"]]
   (1.5ms)  COMMIT
  Item Exists (1.0ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "items" WHERE "items"."search_id" = $1 AND "items"."collection_id" = 1 LIMIT $2  [["search_id", 54], ["LIMIT", 1]]
   (0.2ms)  BEGIN
  Collection Load (0.9ms)  SELECT  "collections".* FROM "collections" WHERE "collections"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  Item Exists (0.7ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "items" WHERE "items"."collection_id" = $1 AND "items"."search_id" = 54 LIMIT $2  [["collection_id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  SQL (0.8ms)  INSERT INTO "items" ("collection_id", "search_id", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4) RETURNING "id"  [["collection_id", 1], ["search_id", 54], ["created_at", "2018-06-18 13:56:30.459078"], ["updated_at", "2018-06-18 13:56:30.459078"]]
   (2.2ms)  COMMIT
  Search Load (0.7ms)  SELECT  "searches".* FROM "searches" WHERE "searches"."term" = $1 ORDER BY "searches"."id" ASC LIMIT $2  [["term", "personalized gift"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
   (0.3ms)  BEGIN
  Search Exists (0.5ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "searches" WHERE "searches"."term" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["term", "personalized gift"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  SQL (0.6ms)  INSERT INTO "searches" ("term", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3) RETURNING "id"  [["term", "personalized gift"], ["created_at", "2018-06-18 13:56:32.460438"], ["updated_at", "2018-06-18 13:56:32.460438"]]
   (2.5ms)  COMMIT
  Item Exists (0.6ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "items" WHERE "items"."search_id" = $1 AND "items"."collection_id" = 1 LIMIT $2  [["search_id", 55], ["LIMIT", 1]]
   (0.2ms)  BEGIN
  Collection Load (0.7ms)  SELECT  "collections".* FROM "collections" WHERE "collections"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  Item Exists (0.7ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "items" WHERE "items"."collection_id" = $1 AND "items"."search_id" = 55 LIMIT $2  [["collection_id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  SQL (0.7ms)  INSERT INTO "items" ("collection_id", "search_id", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4) RETURNING "id"  [["collection_id", 1], ["search_id", 55], ["created_at", "2018-06-18 13:56:32.474614"], ["updated_at", "2018-06-18 13:56:32.474614"]]
   (1.1ms)  COMMIT
  Search Load (0.8ms)  SELECT  "searches".* FROM "searches" WHERE "searches"."term" = $1 ORDER BY "searches"."id" ASC LIMIT $2  [["term", "book smell"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
   (0.5ms)  BEGIN
  Search Exists (0.8ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "searches" WHERE "searches"."term" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["term", "book smell"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  SQL (0.7ms)  INSERT INTO "searches" ("term", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3) RETURNING "id"  [["term", "book smell"], ["created_at", "2018-06-18 13:56:34.573441"], ["updated_at", "2018-06-18 13:56:34.573441"]]
   (1.3ms)  COMMIT
  Item Exists (0.6ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "items" WHERE "items"."search_id" = $1 AND "items"."collection_id" = 1 LIMIT $2  [["search_id", 56], ["LIMIT", 1]]
   (0.1ms)  BEGIN
  Collection Load (1.4ms)  SELECT  "collections".* FROM "collections" WHERE "collections"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  Item Exists (0.6ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "items" WHERE "items"."collection_id" = $1 AND "items"."search_id" = 56 LIMIT $2  [["collection_id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  SQL (0.6ms)  INSERT INTO "items" ("collection_id", "search_id", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4) RETURNING "id"  [["collection_id", 1], ["search_id", 56], ["created_at", "2018-06-18 13:56:34.585728"], ["updated_at", "2018-06-18 13:56:34.585728"]]
   (2.5ms)  COMMIT
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/collections/1
Completed 302 Found in 24422ms (ActiveRecord: 153.5ms)
```

The amount of items I'm inserting varies but even between many different examples, PG always takes longer, even though when looking at those two logs I posted, it seems like SQLite3 is taking longer per transaction.
Is this normal or is there something I can do to optimize it?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you give us a hint as to what we are supposed to be looking at? All those queries seem to be under 1ms so I'm not sure I'd have much confidence in the precise timings anyway. I think what I'm saying is "do you have a question"?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like `ActiveRecord` is responding pretty quickly for both databases:

Sqlite: `ActiveRecord: 12.3ms`

Postgres:  `ActiveRecord: 153.5ms`

While Postgres is certainly higher, I would think both of those response times would be acceptable, and that they would vary slightly each time you hit that action.

You do, however, have some sort of redirect taking place `302 Redirected to http://localhost:3000/collections/1` that seems to be adding a bunch of time to the request.

You might try making sure that there are no scripts on that page that are gumming up the works. Also, you might make sure that the indexes have been applied to your Postgres database, and also make sure your collections page doesn't have any `n+1` queries.

Hard to say more with the limited information given in the question,